# Ideas for a believable power scaling system

Tags: magic, balancing-magic-systems, power-scaling

**Problem:** I need a way to make believable certain characters becoming much stronger than normally humanly possible, in a way which most people could not replicate.

**Elaboration:** I’m worldbuilding for a story set in a space empire, in which certain creatures (as well as many humans) can use magic.

I want to have many of the story-important characters to become much more powerful than normally possible, but I want there to be in such a way that it would not be easily replicable by random people not directly in the story, or be something that characters could have already been doing before the story. That rules out simply leaving it up to hard work for me, since anyone can work hard.

I once read a story with a similar setting that solved this problem using what they called “Quintessence Drain”, in which all living creatures contained an essence called Quintessence, which could be extracted using an obscure technique, which would add the extracted essence to the user’s own strength. The protagonists got access to this ability, and used it to keep up with the story’s power creep as they progressively fought enemies further and further beyond their natural limits. It also allowed the increase in strength to be natural and constant, rather than relying on irregular power boosts.

However, I do not feel that this type of vampiric spell would fit in the story I am currently writing, so I’m looking for a replacement.

(Sidenote, I’m reluctant to go for solutions that increase the characters magical strength, since I want physical strength to be heavily emphasized as well, and some characters have little to no innate magical ability at all. I’m willing to bend the rules and allow these characters to use a spell that solves the power creep problem, though.)

If anyone has any suggestions that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey Mozila! This is an interesting question, but it would be great if you could change it a little bit. Rather than fishing for ideas, try to rephrase your question or try to find another question on the Worldbuilding page that can help you with your question. Thanks!

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the trite solutions are either that the character has an innate ability (genetic, spiritual/magical, "midiclorians", etc.) that can be steadily trained to superhuman levels or they are lucky enough to receive access to a medical implant, treatment (magical or scientific), artifact, etc. that boosts their abilities to superhuman levels that is rare, expensive, is only compatible with a few people, etc.  If those aren't what you're looking for, perhaps try clarifying the question further?

Comment: He's not even sure himself at first, but he does keep getting stung by bees on an annoyingly regular basis. He hears a folktale that mother nature will bestow her gift on the worthy, and only she can decide the form of that gift. Will there ever be any kind of definitive confirmation from the great mother herself? Up to the writer.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding Mozila, Take a [Tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) or take a look at the [Help Center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help). We don't do "Idea Generation" -type questions as it violates the Stack Exchange "One specific question, one specific answer" format. I recommend reformatting this to something like: I have these restrictions, A,B,C. Is my system balanced? Best answers will include X/Y.

Comment: Hi Mozila. I'd be willing to VTR this question if you could [edit] it and explain (a) exactly and specifically (the mantra of StackExchange) *what* "power" you are expecting to enhance. Please pick only one. (b) Provide an example of *why* the "power" needs to be enhanced. (c) Explain *how much* the "power" must increase. (d) explain "how quickly" the power must increase. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's a wide-open question you've got there. Let's see how many buses I can fit through it.

#### Genetics

Back in the dawn of time, when the universe was young and the dominant life forms were *very* dominant, one particular species of Precursors rose to power by sheer physical ability. Their particular advantage was a mutation that caused their bodies to develop tremendous physical power with exposure to certain types of magical energy. After they were almost wiped out by a weaker but far more numerous enemy (who subsequently fell when a magical experiment went slightly wrong and blew up their sun), the few survivors went into hiding. Millions of years later their genetic lines have been diluted, their many populations have evolved and changed, and the genes responsible for their remarkable physical abilities have been almost eradicated.

Almost.

In several of their descendant species there are a few blood lines that have retained some fragments of the genetic sequence that granted the Precursors their enormous physical potential. Every once in a while a pairing produces an exceptional child whose gene sequence includes a larger fragment of the gene, making them physically greater than their peers. Without the specific magical energies however these specimens rarely exceed the racial maximums by much, if at all. And those energies simply aren't common.

This all changes of course when the first space travelers - all taken from the best available people of their generation - leave their backwater home worlds and travel the local stars. Exposure to new and interesting 'radiations' stimulates the few on board who inherited the genes, greatly increasing their physical attributes.

#### Breeding / Eugenics / Tinkering

Same thing, different source. A long-term breeding program to produce the most physically capable people stumbles on a combination of genetics that produces the same effect. Or perhaps it wasn't so haphazard as a breeding program, perhaps someone did a little gene therapy that produced the effect. Either way, a small percentage of the resulting people develop the ability to absorb specific forms of magical energy and use it to alter their bodies. Denser bones, better muscle fiber development, increased oxygen exchange, resistance to disease, more efficient nerve linkage... the list goes on.

The breeding program may not even be one that they know about. An unknown external agent - the remnants of an Elder Race for instance - has decided they need to produce super men and women to continue their job of protecting the universe. A shadowy cult of Aldebaran Supremacists want to prove that Aldebaran Lizard-Badgers are the ultimate species in the galaxy, and if they're not then we'll damned well make them. Or maybe some Ryxellet researcher got bored and decided to play god for a few millennia with the mayflies. Maybe we'll never know.

#### Magitech Remnants

Over the history of the universe many different species have risen to greatness and fallen, leaving behind amazing lostech devices that nobody can quite get a handle on. They don't seem to follow the rules of nature as we know them, and most of them don't seem to do anything at all. Most of these devices are broken, or calibrated for a form of life that is completely alien to the species that found them, but they still try to perform their original function even after incredible amounts of time have passed. Several such devices were originally created to assist in the development of hardier warriors during times of war. The war is long over, but the machines are still working. And by machines I mean the interfaces to vast magical systems that have been refining energy since before the dinosaurs existed.

For no apparent reason, one of these systems will discharge some of that energy into a nearby creature. Focused as it is through incredibly complex spellcraft, that energy changes the being in subtle but profound ways. Mitochondria are upgraded, the entire ATP cycle is replaced with something far more potent, cell walls are fortified with magical scaffolding and so on.

#### Fate (and other godly powers)

Almost every civilization that has ever existed has generated pantheons of deities at some point in their history. While they often share similarities to each other - almost everyone has a Farmer, a Fighter, a Fool and so on - the only god that every single religion creates independently is Fate. The details differ, but somewhere in every species religious past there is a god that weaves the tapestry of the future, that plucks individuals from the common hordes and elevates them to heroic status or dooms them to eternal frustration.

Why? Well, the stories differ. It'd be nice to think that the prevailing view of Fate working towards some grand utopia were true, but if there's an intellect behind the workings of Fate then it's probably just pulling our collective chains for the lolz. Yes, I said it, Fate is a universe-spanning troll with nothing better to do than push the insignificant little life forms around. Presumably to relieve the boredom.

#### Magic is trippy!

OK, so you know how everything is made of, like, vibrations and stuff? We're all just frequencies, man!

My inner Flower Child aside, it turns out that in a way that's not entirely wrong... just on a different level. It has long been known by some races that every sentient has a complex energy field - an aura, or perhaps a soul. The nature of it is still being investigated, but it's ultimately responsible for how you personally interact with the magical energies of the universe. Careful measurements can show the effects of practicing magic and how different types of magic have different effects on you energy field. The field also interacts with your body in some way that we just can't quite figure out, even by disassembling a few thousand test subjects. Don't worry though, plenty more where those came fr... Umm... pretend you didn't read that last bit. Please?

Anyway... for whatever reason, physically capable people have some interesting things going on with their aura. It looks a lot like building up your physical abilities alters your aura. Body builders, athletes, warriors... all of them develop certain features in their energy fields as they improve.

We're so present in the physical that we often can't see the ethereal at all, let alone judge it accurately. If we were more focused on the astral plane it might be more obvious that these physical abilities form because of anomalies in a person's energy field, not the other way around. And the more exposure you have to energies attuned to those anomalies in your aura the more effect they have on your physical development.

#### Everyone else just sucks.

That might be a little unfair. Perhaps it'd be better to say that all life, everywhere, is being suppressed in some way. Ethereal parasites cluster around living beings, slowly draining away their vital energies, infecting their offspring in the egg, generally causing sub-optimal development and reduced life expectancy. They're incredibly hard to detect, maybe even virtually impossible without the right mix of magic and luck. Everybody has them, they're so ubiquitous that even when they are detected they get mistaken for some fundamental element of life.

But for some reason they just don't like some people. Their energies are wrong, they taste bad, something like that. Maybe it's genetic, maybe it's some mutation in their life energy, we don't know... but those lucky few get to grow strong while everyone around them is sucked dry. They get the full, unfiltered development experience that everyone else is held back from, and the difference is striking. Imagine you have one person who is well fed their whole lives while everyone else is forced to live on a starvation diet the whole time, barely taking in enough calories to move while the well-fed person has everything they need to grow healthy and strong.

That person would be far more powerful than the rest, on a whole other level than anyone who has grown up being drained of their full potential.

#### Astrology!

Another common theme, but everyone knows that astrology is pure fakery and self-delusion... except that there are currents of magic that flow between the stars, like gossamer threads of power, a web of magic that stirs the fabric of reality as the galaxies turn. When they pass through planets they stir up the ley lines, disrupt the flow of mana, cause all sorts of mayhem for the magical communities... and sometimes they just pass through quietly, unremarked by anyone.

Every now and then, when the stars align just right, a confluence of galactic ley lines passes close enough to twist reality just a tiny bit. A child conceived in such a disturbed section of space - sometimes as small as a few feet across - will be born with potentials far higher than most.

---

I'll leave it there, but I'm sure you can see that there are many possibilities. Broadly they fall into a couple of main categories: internal and external. Your heroes were born to be gods among men (and women), or some outside force thrust that greatness upon them. Even the internal options aren't all that cut and dried - they range from "it just is" through to the classic "scion of an elder bloodline."

And yes, a lot of the above is based on stories I've read. Doc Smith's Lensman saga is very much about purposeful breeding of powerful bloodlines, resulting in super-powered individuals whose purpose is to save the universe... and the series was one of my favorite reads as an early teen. Space Opera is my guilty pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

**BONDING WITH AN ENERGY CREATURE**

In the hyperspace of your universe lives a race of creatures of pure hyper-energy. It is possible for some people to bond with such a creature, at great personal risk, gaining access to immense power drawn from hyperspace that can manifest in various ways, depending on the exact nature of the creature and of the human it bonds with.

Bonding with a human is the only way that the energy creatures can leave hyperspace, and bonding may be an intelligent choice that allows the creatures to explore and experience a material cosmos. The creatures can easily understand the needs of their hosts and (usually) respond to lend aid in the way the hosts wants, whether energy tricks, increased strength, flight, teleportation, telepathy or other "magic" effects (which, as mentioned above, may be limited by the exact nature of the bond). It is, however, difficult for humans to understand the needs of their bonded energy creature. Or two-way communication may instead be easy, and dialogue between host and creature could add to your story,

It may be necessary for the energy creatures to regularly visit hyperspace to recharge, possibly even temporarily leaving their hosts, making them vulnerable in the meanwhile. It may even be that some host/creature mixes are required to safely travel through hyperspace and that these are members of a guild with great economic and political influence (like the Spacing Guild in *Dune*).

Answer (score 0):

**Zordon.**

[image: zordon]

https://powerrangers.fandom.com/wiki/Zordon

Or some Zordon equivalent.  Zordon was a character in the might Morphin Power Ramgers series.  Being a head in a jar, more or less, Zordon was not much on the doing.  Instead he mentored the Power Rangers, bestowing upon them larger and larger powers as they matured.

So too for your folks.  They have a mentor of some sort who parcels out the superness little by little.